# PDO Query Error Scripts

Tags: php, pdo

I finally got my first PDO query to work - a simple row count query. I'm still struggling with more complex queries (fetch, etc.). Before I move on, I need to get a handle on error reporting.

My goal is to create TWO PDO queries - one for use online and a local query that maximizes error messages. At the very least, I'd like to know if I'm not connected to my database. Can PDO also tell me if I've connected to a database table that doesn't exist or if there's an error in the way I cited a table field? I can presumably continue doing this with phpMyAdmin > SQL in most cases, but it looks like that won't work with some PDO-modified queries.

```
switch(PHP_OS)
{
 case 'Linux':
 // (Online query)
 break;
 default:
 // (Local query with error reporting)
 break;
}
```

So far, I've tried two different database connection schemes...

```
// FIRST DB CONNECTION...
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST_NAME;dbname=DATABASENAME;charset=utf8', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}

// SECOND DB CONNECTION...
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'USERNAME','PASSWORD', $opt);
```

The first one tells me if I'm not properly connected to my database, but none of the PDO queries I've experimented with work with it. My queries do work with the second connection ($dsn), but there's no error reporting at all.

In summary, the code below appears to work for my simple row(count) query and can presumably be used online as is. But can someone tell me how to enhance it for maximum error reporting locally?

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DATABASE;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'USERNAME','PASSWORD', $opt);

$sql= "SELECT COUNT(URL) AS num FROM people
WHERE URL = :url";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':url',$MyURL,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$Total = $stmt->fetch();

// This query works, also...
// $sql= "SELECT URL FROM people
// WHERE URL = '$MyURL'";
// $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
// $stmt->execute();
// $Total = $stmt->rowCount();

switch($Total['num'])
{
 case 1;
 // SUCCESS! Include appropriate files.
 break;
 case 0;
 // ERROR 404 - NOT FOUND
 break;
 default:
 // MULTIPLE RESULTS; HANDLE AS NEEDED
 break;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't understand the idea of error reporting. It have to be ALWAYS maximized.

It's *destination* that differs.

On a local setup make your **whole PHP** display errors on-screen:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

On a live server make your **whole PHP** display NOT a single error, but make them al logged:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
```

From the above you can also tell that first PDO connect example is absolutely inacceptable and should never be used.